# How to use ChromePushNotification in PHP

Tags: php, google-chrome-extension, push-notification

I need to push notification to user , when new task is assigned to the user, I am planning to use "ChomePushNotification" , but i could not understand how to use it in php to invoke notification..

https://storage-cdn.realtime.co/chrome-push/index.html

Can anyone give me the overview how to use this in PHP , to invoke notification if a record inserted in a table "Task" with **agent_id =123**, i need to send notification to **user "123"**.. **"NEW TASK ASSIGNE.."**

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to use javascript to give the user the option to subscribe to the push notifications...

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    console.log('Service Worker is supported');
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js').then(function(reg) {
        console.log(':^)', reg);
        reg.pushManager.subscribe({
            userVisibleOnly: true
        }).then(function(sub) {
            console.log('endpoint:', sub.endpoint);
        });
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(':^(', error);
    });
}
```

The next step is to use cURL to send the request to Google using the following cURL command, either from the command line or by extrapolating it into a PHP cURL command...

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=AIzaSyAc2e8MeZHA5NfhPANea01wnyeQD7uVY0c" --header "Content-Type: application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration\_ids\":[\"APA91bE9DAy6\_p9bZ9I58rixOv-ya6PsNMi9Nh5VfV4lpXGw1wS6kxrkQbowwBu17ryjGO0ExDlp-S-mCiwKc5HmVNbyVfylhgwITXBYsmSszpK0LpCxr9Cc3RgxqZD7614SqDokwsc3vIEXkaT8OPIM-mnGMRYG1-hsarEU4coJWNjdFP16gWs\"]}"
```

Please note the cURL example is take directly from the Google Developers page at https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/step-07?hl=en and uses their sample hashes and keys.

For further information you can review the details of how to send push notifications by checking out the Google documentation at https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/?hl=en